# Ostrogradsky's method for isolation of rational part of an integral

Tags: calculus

$$
 \int{\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\mbox{d}x} = \frac{P_{1}(x)}{Q_{1}(x)}+\int{\frac{P_{2}(x)}{Q_{2}(x)}\mbox{d}x}\\
\deg P(x) < \deg Q(x)\\
\deg P_{1}(x) < \deg Q_{1}(x)\\
\deg P_{2}(x) < \deg Q_{2}(x)\\
Q_{1}(x) = GCD(Q(x),Q'(x))\\
Q(x) = Q_{1}(x)Q_{2}(x)\\
$$

$$
\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=\frac{P_{1}'(x)Q_{1}(x)-P_{1}(x)Q_{1}'(x)}{(Q_{1}(x))^2}+\frac{P_{2}(x)}{Q_{2}(x)}\\
\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=\frac{P_{1}'(x)Q_{1}(x)Q_{2}(x)-P_{1}(x)Q_{1}'(x)Q_{2}(x)+P_{2}(x)(Q_{1}(x))^2}{(Q_{1}(x))^2Q_{2}(x)}\\
\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=\frac{P_{1}'(x)Q_{1}(x)Q_{2}(x)-P_{1}(x)Q_{1}'(x)Q_{2}(x)+P_{2}(x)(Q_{1}(x))^2}{Q_{1}(x)Q(x)}\\
\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=\frac{Q_{1}(x)(P_{1}'(x)Q_{2}(x)-P_{1}(x)\frac{Q_{2}(x)Q_{1}'(x)}{Q_{1}(x)}+P_{2}(x)Q_{1}(x))}{Q_{1}(x)Q(x)}
$$
Let $$ H(x) = \frac{Q_{2}(x)Q_{1}'(x)}{Q_{1}(x)}$$

Prove or disprove that H(x) is always a polynomial 
My conjecture is that statement H(x) is always a polynomial is true

Comment: hint $Q_1|Q^{\prime}$.

Comment: How can it help Here in the numerator we have Q_{1}'

Comment: Following @ReneSchipperus suggestion, just take the derivative in $Q=Q_1Q_2$ and then divide both sides by $Q_1$

Comment: Albert and afer this what you wrote i should use Rene's hint ?

Comment: I came to my conjecture by consideration possible factorization of Q , $Q_{1}$ and $Q_{2}$ factors of $Q_{1}$ in $Q_{1}'$ are counted one less times then they are counted in $Q_{1}$ but there is $Q_{2}$ in which factors of $Q_{1}$ are counted only once Thats how i came to my conjecture